# How to get months in R when my data has attribute 'hours since'?

Tags: r, date

I am working with monthly climate data and I want to get the dates the data covers in the form of yyyy-mm such as 2015-01, 2015-02, etc. The attribute of the dataset says 'hours since 1800-1-1 00:00:00'. The data actually covers the period from 1948-2015 at monthly resolution.

I tried the following but both are not giving me what I expect:

```
months<-as.POSIXlt(time_slp, origin='1800-1-1 00:00:00')

months<-as.Date(time_slp,  origin ="1800-1-1 00:00:00")
```

Sample `time_slp`:

```
time_slp <- c(1569072, 1569816, 1570488, 1571232, 1571952, 1572696, 1573416, 1574160, 1574904, 1575624)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `time_slp`? Maybe `as.POSIXct("1800-01-01 00:00:00")+as.difftime(time_slp, units="hours")` could help

Comment: time_slp[1:10]
 [1] 1569072 1569816 1570488 1571232 1571952 1572696 1573416
 [8] 1574160 1574904 1575624

Comment: Include your sample in the question, so anybody can see it. See my edited comment above.

Comment: looks like @nicola answered it -- if you're expecting this sample to get you dates in 1979

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
as.POSIXct("1800-01-01 00:00:00")+as.difftime(time_slp, units="hours")
```

To know the month of each date, just use `months`:

```
months(as.POSIXct("1800-01-01 00:00:00")+as.difftime(time_slp, units="hours"))
```

To have it in the format you asked in the comments, try `strftime` (say `x` is the object obtained from my first line):

```
strftime(x,format="%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola. Is there a way to get the date in the form of yyyy-mm such as 1990-01, 1990-02, ..., 2015-01, 2015-06?

Comment: Great thanks. Actually, in the dataset the data for each month is placed at the end of the previous month. The data starts in Jan -1948 but when I use strftime, it drops the days even if it is the end of the month. Is there a way to deal with it?   time_slp[1:5]
[1] "1947-12-31 23:56:02 EST" "1948-01-31 23:56:02 EST"
[3] "1948-02-29 23:56:02 EST" "1948-03-31 23:56:02 EST"
[5] "1948-05-01 00:56:02 EDT"